# Quartz Scheduler not triggering the job when configured via Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

Ive being from sometime trying to setup a little program that uses Spring and Quartz together to schedule a task. I followed some other similar answers with no luck.
At the moment I think I have all configured correctly, I see no more exceptions but my job looks like its not kicking off.

In the log.out that Spring generates, I see the following messages at the end:

> 2015-06-04T15:46:57.928 DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver]
>   Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in
>   [systemProperties] 2015-06-04T15:46:57.929 DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver]
>   Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in
>   [systemEnvironment] 2015-06-04T15:46:57.929 DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] Could
>   not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property
>   source. Returning [null]

I will show you my codes...

This is the class from which I start the scheduler:

```
public class JobRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SchedulerException {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(WhatsTheTimeConfiguration.class);
        AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory autowiringSpringBeanJobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
        autowiringSpringBeanJobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

        SpringBeanJobFactory springBeanJobFactory = new SpringBeanJobFactory();

        SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        schedulerFactoryBean.setTriggers(trigger());
        schedulerFactoryBean.setJobFactory(springBeanJobFactory);
        schedulerFactoryBean.start();
    }

    private static SimpleTrigger trigger() {
        return newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("whatsTheTimeJobTrigger", "jobsGroup1")
                .startNow()
                .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
                        .withIntervalInSeconds(1)
                        .repeatForever())
                .build();
    }

}
```

I want to mention that If I use the method schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler().start(), it throws me a null pointer exception on the scheduler, so thats why im calling start() on the factory.

The class AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory was copy pasted from another answer here in stackoverflow. I decided to do that since all other answers where I found something was only configuration done via xml and I don't want to use xml.

```
public final class AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory extends SpringBeanJobFactory implements
        ApplicationContextAware {

    private transient AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext context) {
        beanFactory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object createJobInstance(final TriggerFiredBundle bundle) throws Exception {
        final Object job = super.createJobInstance(bundle);
        beanFactory.autowireBean(job);
        return job;
    }
}
```

This is the class that represents the Job that I want to trigger:

```
@Component
public class WhatsTheTimeManager extends QuartzJobBean {

    @Autowired
    private WhatsTheTime usecase;
    @Autowired
    private LocationRetriever locationDataProvider;

    public WhatsTheTimeManager() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        usecase.tellMeWhatsTheTimeIn(locationDataProvider.allLocations());
    }

    public void setUsecase(WhatsTheTime usecase) {
        this.usecase = usecase;
    }

    public void setLocationDataProvider(LocationRetriever locationDataProvider) {
        this.locationDataProvider = locationDataProvider;
    }
}
```

My Spring configuration is doing component scanning, its very simple:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.springpractice")
public class WhatsTheTimeConfiguration {

}
```

From this point everything I have are just some interfaces, components and a domain object, but I will paste them also, just in case I forgot something:

```
public interface LocationRetriever {
    List<String> allLocations();
}
```

---

```
public interface TimeOutputRenderer {
    TimeReport renderReport(String timeInLocation, String location);
}
```

---

```
public interface TimeRetriever {
    String timeFor(String location);
}
```

---

```
@Component
public class LocationRetrieverDataProvider implements LocationRetriever{

    public LocationRetrieverDataProvider() {
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> allLocations() {
        return asList("Europe/London", "Europe/Madrid", "Europe/Moscow", "Asia/Tokyo", "Australia/Melbourne", "America/New_York");
    }
}
```

---

```
@Component
public class TimeOutputRendererDataProvider implements TimeOutputRenderer {

    public TimeOutputRendererDataProvider() {
    }

    @Override
    public TimeReport renderReport(String location, String time) {
        System.out.println(location + " time is " + time);
        return new TimeReport(location, time);
    }
}
```

---

```
@Component
public class TimeRetrieverDataProvider implements TimeRetriever {

    public TimeRetrieverDataProvider() {
    }

    @Override
    public String timeFor(String location) {
        SimpleDateFormat timeInLocation = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
        timeInLocation.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(location));
        return timeInLocation.format(new Date());
    }
}
```

Just one last detail, that maybe is of interest. 
The versions I am using in my libraries are the following:

quartz 2.2.1

spring 4.1.6.RELEASE

When I run the appliaction, I expect the times of those countries to be printed every second, but it doesn't happen.

If you want to clone the code and try for yourself and see, you can find it at this git repo(Feel free to fork if you want): https://github.com/SFRJ/cleanarchitecture

Comment: Not sure what do you mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main error in your code is that you're not letting Spring handle the scheduling for you.

While you can use Quartz in code as any other code, the idea of the integration with Spring is to tell Spring about the work you want to be done and let Spring do the hard work for you.

In order to allow Spring to run the Quartz scheduling, you need to declare the Job, the JobDetail and the Trigger as Beans.

Spring only handles Beans if they are created through the Spring life-cycle (i.e. using annotations or XML) but not if the objects are created in code with a `new` statement.

The following code needs to be removed from `JobRunner.java`:

```
SpringBeanJobFactory springBeanJobFactory = new SpringBeanJobFactory();

SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
schedulerFactoryBean.setTriggers(trigger());
schedulerFactoryBean.setJobFactory(springBeanJobFactory);
schedulerFactoryBean.start();
...
private static SimpleTrigger trigger() {
    return newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("whatsTheTimeJobTrigger", "jobsGroup1")
            .startNow()
            .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
                    .withIntervalInSeconds(1)
                    .repeatForever())
            .build();
}
```

That code will have to be re-written into `WhatsTheTimeConfiguration.java`, and here's how it looks now:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.djordje.cleanarchitecture")
public class WhatsTheTimeConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {
        SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        schedulerFactoryBean.setTriggers(trigger());
        schedulerFactoryBean.setJobDetails(jobDetail());
        schedulerFactoryBean.setJobFactory(springBeanJobFactory());
        return schedulerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringBeanJobFactory springBeanJobFactory() {
        return new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobDetail jobDetail() {
        JobDetailImpl jobDetail = new JobDetailImpl();
        jobDetail.setKey(new JobKey("WhatsTheTime"));
        jobDetail.setJobClass(WhatsTheTimeManager.class);
        jobDetail.setDurability(true);
        return jobDetail;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleTrigger trigger() {
        return newTrigger()
                .forJob(jobDetail())
                .withIdentity("whatsTheTimeJobTrigger", "jobsGroup1")
                .startNow()
                .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
                        .withIntervalInSeconds(1)
                        .repeatForever())
                .build();
    }
}
```

`SchedulerFactoryBean` is now a Bean and will be handled and initialized by Spring, and so are `SimpleTrigger` and `AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory`.

I added the missing `JobDetail` class which was missing and added the necessary wiring to `SimpleTrigger` and `SchedulerFactoryBean`. They both need to know about `JobDetail` which is the only place that knows which class is the job class that needs to be triggered.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, makes completely sense. It works prefectly now... great answer.